# Count the number of inputs in a page

Tags: codeigniter

Is there a way I can count the number of inputs in a single page?

Say if the page has 5 inputs, a save button will appear- and if there is no inputs on the page, the save button will not appear. How do i do this?

i have this but i dont think this is right

```
<script>
var x = 0;
var ins = 0;
$(':input').each(function(){
    x++;
});
ins = x;
```

and pass the ins variable to php like

```
<?php echo '<script>ins</script>';?>
```

but it doesnt echo anything? is the code right tho

Comment: Javascript can show/hide inputs. if you want to do this with php, it's better to attach your PHP code to your question.

Comment: You can't pass javascript results to php unless you are using ajax.

Comment: how to? I dont really have idea on ajax.

Comment: What you actually want to do? Show the button if there are five input fields or only when all the five inputs are filled in?

Comment: show if there are input fields, either filled in or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two line code is enough for you.If you have not any input fields the submit button will be automatically hide.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
console.log(inputs);
alert(inputs.length);
if(inputs.length==0)
{
 document.querySelector('#button').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name1" value="1111974167" />
<input type="text" name="name2" value="1392666449" />
<input type="text" name="name3" value="1329903177" />
<input type="text" name="name4" value="913532785" />
<button id="button">submit</button>
```

JS fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/njv5e8yc/1/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you actually need to have JavaScript be echoed in php since you can determine count in the first line, but you can not pass javascript to php without ajax. Here is a basic example:

**/index.php**

```
<input type="text" name="name1" value="1111974167" />
<input type="text" name="name2" value="1392666449" />
<input type="text" name="name3" value="1329903177" />
<input type="text" name="name4" value="913532785" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Get the count of the inputs found
    var x = $('input').length;
    // Pass the count to php
    $.ajax({
        url: '/count.php',
        data: {
            "count": x
        },
        type: 'post',
        // This is what happens with the ajax returns from count.php
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**/count.php**

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['count'])) {
    $count  =   $_POST['count'];
    die('The count is: '.$count);
}
```

You would get an alert dialogue box that says:

> The count is: 4

Comment: Is the ajax call is required here? If the count is pre-defined you can directly pass it to the javascript variable by echoing it

Comment: @AjeshAV That's what is said in my first sentence. The OP is unclear about what the final requirement is so I am giving an answer that counts the inputs in js and passes to php. I have no idea what the OP is intending to do with value.

Comment: @AjeshAV That is to say that I don't know why they would like to pass it to PHP or if the OP even needs it to be in PHP, but the example is using PHP to echo the value. The code suggests they expect that `echo "<script>ins</script>";` should write `5`. That tells me they are not familiar with how the two different languages work in conjunction with each other. My guess is they only need the first line of the JavaScript (using `.length`), but I can not be 100% certain, ergo I have demonstrated how to pass JS to PHP as well.